# Clarification Android Activity onPause and onRestart

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

I have a question regarding the activity lifecycle in Android. When I have code like this (With correct names)

```
 newActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Info",correctInfo);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Then 'NextActivity' comes in the foreground. But does this mean that 'MainActivity' has stopped? According to the graph below, 'MainActivity' is no longer visible so it has stopped too?

EDIT:
And what if I have a chain of 3 activities. Is the first one still not destroyed?

[image: Activity lifecycle graph]

Comment: Yes, it will be stopped.

Comment: You can simply create 2 3 Activities and add all lifecycle method and set log inside All the method and check by your self. It would be great.

Comment: Don't use application context to start activities

Comment: Yes, the activity will be stopped i.e; onstop() method will call in Activity A and in Activity B onResume() method will call

Answer (score 0):

The activities will only be destroyed in case you implicitly finish them with `finish()` or related methods, or if by any necessary reason, most of the times related with your device running out of memory, the system kills them when they are in the background. If none of the previous occur, your activities that go in the background will reach the `onStop()` state of their lifecycle, until they come to the foreground again, as the graph clearly shows.

So answering your question, in case you have a flow of:

A -> B -> C if you dont call finish in any of them and the system does not kill any of the activities in the background, both A and B will be stopped, but not destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity will be stopped as soon as it becomes invisible and another activity comes in the foreground. In case of a chain of activities being launched one after other, all will be in a stopped state(unless the system destroys the activity for freeing memory and resources).

Answer (score 0):

[Please read this article on back stack and task management](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)

In android the activities or tasks (collection of activities) are arranged in a stack, known as The Back Stack.

When a new activity is started by the current activity, the new activity is pushed to the top of the stack and takes focus. The previous activity also remains in the stack, but it is in stopped state with system retaining its state of user interface so it can be resumed. Similarly, if this new activity again creates another activity, the newly created activity will go to top of the stack and the current activity will move to stopped state.

Once a back button is pressed, the activity on top is finished and popped off the stack, and the immediate next activity in the stack is resumed with the saved instance state, hence giving a feel like resuming where it was left.

For a chain, say you have three activities, A, B, and C. A starts B and B starts C. So when C is in focus, your A and B activities will be in stopped state (but still in back stack). You can press back on C and resume B, then press back on B and resume A. As mentioned above, once back is pressed, the current activity is popped from the stack and is finished.

From the same URL I shared on top:

> Note: Multiple tasks can be held in the background at once. However,
>   if the user is running many background tasks at the same time, the
>   system might begin destroying background activities in order to
>   recover memory, causing the activity states to be lost.